# Showing a monthly trend by group?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID    Date      Freq      Gender      Trt      month   Group
    15 A1 2019-01-29     1       female       1          1      G1                                  
    16 A1 2019-04-27     10      female       1          4      G1                                  
    17 A1 2019-04-27     10      female       1          4      G1                                     
    18 A1 2019-04-29     2       female       1          4      G1                                
    19 A1 2019-04-29     12      female       1          4      G1                                      
    20 A1 2019-10-09     6       female       1          10     G1                                      
    21 A1 2019-12-26     NA      female       1          12     G1                                     
    22 A1 2019-12-26     NA      female       1          12     G1                                     
    27 A1 2019-02-19     5       female       1          2      G1                                    
    28 A2 2019-02-19     15      male         0          2      G3
    37 A3 2019-01-30     NA      female       0          1      G2
    38 A3 2019-01-30     9       female       0          1      G2
    39 A3 2019-02-15     11      female       0          2      G2
    40 A3 2019-02-15     10      female       0          2      G2
    41 A3 2019-03-16     1       female       0          3      G2
    42 A3 2019-04-01     1       female       0          4      G2
    43 A3 2019-04-01     3       female       0          4      G2
    44 A3 2019-04-22     2       female       0          4      G2
    45 A3 2019-05-25     4       female       0          5      G2
    46 A3 2019-05-29     4       female       0          5      G2
    47 A3 2019-06-06     19      female       0          6      G2")
```

and i want to show the trend of the different groups G1-6 and trt by month. so like, a graph with month 1-12 on the xbar and count of how many in that month on the ybar grouped by G (so a different colored trend line for G1, G2, etc. on the graph showing how the group numbers dropped or rose in that month), or even another form of descriptive statistics would be helpful. but i can't figure out how to get any graphs to work. I already made separate columns for year, and tried making a column for group but it just won't graph?
Here's what I've done and tried:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
dfDates <- data.frame(year = as.numeric(format(df$Date, format = "%Y")), month = as.numeric(format(df$Date, format = "%m")))
dfDates <- cbind(df,dfDates)

dfG <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4","G5","G6"), names_to = "Group", names_ptypes = list(Group = factor()), values_to = "Value") %>%
  filter(Value == 1) %>%
  select(-Value)

ggplot(dfG, aes(factor(month), sum(Group), group = Group, Trt)) +
  geom_line(size = 1, alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  scale_color_brewer(name = "Name", palette = "Set1")+xlab("month") + ylab("trend")

ggplot(dfG, aes(factor(month), Group)) +
  geom_line(size = 1, alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  scale_color_brewer(name = "name", palette = "Set1")+xlab("month") + ylab("trend")
```

I really appreciate your time and help, thank you.

Comment: Can you share your data (or an extract of it) by getting `structure(df)` and pasting the result in your question?

Comment: I think you want the number in each group in each month -- is that right?

Comment: Yes that's right. And i can try.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to create the summary first, then pass to `ggplot()`, either in a pipe, or by first defining a new object in your environment. (which I prefer)

```r
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- 
  df %>%
  mutate(month = factor(month.abb[month], levels = month.abb)) %>%
  group_by(month, Group) %>%
  summarise(count = max(row_number())) 
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'month'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.

ggplot(df2, aes(month, count)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Group, group = Group), size = 1, alpha = 0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I tried and got this error:Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for your help!